# vb.Net String Parsing

Tags: vb.net, string, parsing

It's been a while since I've worked with **VB.NET** and I don't have my old code to refer to, so some help would be great. 
I have one `input textbox` that accepts two different String values separated by a comma. On button click, I need the input to output to three other `textboxes`, two for the individual string values and the last `textbox` for the string values in reverse order.

For example: `Textbox1` input *"Doe, John"*, then on button click `Textbox2` output *"John"*, `Textbox3` output *"Doe"*, `Textbox4` output *"John.Doe"*.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Search for string.Split and string.Join

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Dim words() As String = TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "").Split(","c)

If words.Length <> 2 Then
    'Throw New Exception... or whatever
Else
    TextBox2.Text = words(0)
    TextBox3.Text = words(1)
    TextBox4.Text = String.Join(".", words)
End If
```

You can modify it to fit your needs, but you get the basic idea.

You can find more information about the methods in MSDN:

- [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)